# Make an autocall programmatically in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Is it possible to do a call to a predefinite number in iphone sdk with some system api?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? It's not quite clear what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this as follows, but the user will need to accept the call placement.

```
NSURL *telephoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:01234567890"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:telephoneURL];
```

If you're attempting to place a call without the user's acknowledgement, then this (thankfully) isn't possible using the public API.